# Find Source Files for OpenGL on Host

Tags: opengl, source-code

I am a newbie to linux. I just installed openGL on ubuntu and would like to tweak some of its source files I use in order to print certain results of some calculations done.

I found the header file I needed using:

```
cd /

sudo find . -name freeglut_std.h
```

I would like to find the corresponding source file. Which is freeglut_std.c I guess. I tried the same command:

```
sudo find . -name freeglut_std.c
```

But nothing was found. How can I find it so I can add a few printf's to the source file?

EDIT: this is the short tutorial I followed in order to install openGL: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=345177

Answer (score 0):

Try making your search case insensitive, add in a wildcard and make it a little faster by specifying a likely directory:

```
sudo find /usr -iname freeglut*
```

This should be enough to find your files, I installed as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
```

and the results of the search showed:

```
andrew@corinth:~$ sudo find /usr -iname freeglut*
[sudo] password for andrew: 
/usr/share/doc/freeglut3
/usr/share/doc/freeglut3-dev
/usr/share/doc/freeglut3-dev/freeglut.html
/usr/share/doc/freeglut3-dev/freeglut_logo.png
/usr/share/doc/freeglut3-dev/freeglut_user_interface.html
/usr/include/GL/freeglut_ext.h
/usr/include/GL/freeglut.h
/usr/include/GL/freeglut_std.h
andrew@corinth:~$
```

The list of files in the freeglut3-dev package can be [seen here...](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/amd64/freeglut3-dev/filelist)

Mind you if you are after the actual `freeglut*.c` files you must download the uncompiled source:

```
sudo apt-get dpkg-dev
mkdir $HOME/Desktop/freeglut_source && cd $HOME/Desktop/freeglut_source
apt-get source freeglut
```

The *.c files will be in `$HOME/Desktop/freeglut_source/freeglut-2.8.1/src`:

```
andrew@corinth:~/Desktop/freeglut_source/freeglut-2.8.1/src$ ls
freeglut_callbacks.c             freeglut_misc.c
freeglut_cursor.c                freeglut_overlay.c
freeglut_display.c               freeglut_spaceball.c
freeglutdll.def                  freeglut_state.c
freeglut_ext.c                   freeglut_stroke_mono_roman.c
freeglut_font.c                  freeglut_stroke_roman.c
freeglut_font_data.c             freeglut_structure.c
freeglut_gamemode.c              freeglut_teapot.c
freeglut_geometry.c              freeglut_teapot_data.h
freeglut_glutfont_definitions.c  freeglut_videoresize.c
freeglut_init.c                  freeglut_window.c
freeglut_input_devices.c         freeglut_xinput.c
freeglut_internal.h              Makefile.am
freeglut_joystick.c              Makefile.in
freeglut_main.c                  templates
freeglut_menu.c
andrew@corinth:~/Desktop/freeglut_source/freeglut-2.8.1/src$
```

Hope that helps. To rebuild the package after your source code changes [have a look here...](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpdatingADeb)

Comment: didn't work. It didn't find any source files

Comment: I have expanded my answer to show how the search goes on my own setup...